# Proof of : "Signature of $\mathbb{C}P^{2n}$ is $1$"

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, orientation

I started learning about signature of a $4k$-manifold and one of the most common example is the signature of $\mathbb{C}P^{2n}$. The only reference I found is [tom Dieck's Algebraic Topology](https://books.google.it/books?id=ruSqmB7LWOcC&pg=PA543&lpg=PA543&dq=tom%20dieck%20algebraic&source=bl&ots=4AAQkrErY_&sig=D0B0ZqES096MISWhdzL4d7xZBes&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBWoVChMI7Pmekd-6yAIVRzIaCh2a_AV9#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Even though the "structure" of the proof (i.e. the idea behind it) seems clear there are some obscure passage in it, first of all, given that strange map $p \colon (\mathbb{C}P^1)^n\to \mathbb{C}P^{2n}$, realising what is the *behaviour* of $p_*$ or $p^*$ for me it's completely impossible.

So I thought about it and realised that maybe there is an easier (but surely sloppier) argument: Recall that $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^{2n};\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(\alpha^{n+1}), |\alpha|=2$. Due to the fact that $H^{4n-1}(\mathbb{C}P^{2n};\mathbb{Z})=0$, then $H^{4n}(\mathbb{C}P^{2n};\mathbb{Z})\cong \hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(H_{4n}(\mathbb{C}P^{2n}); \mathbb{Z})$, so we can choose the generator of $H^{4n}(\mathbb{C}P^{2n};\mathbb{Z})$ as the dual of $[\mathbb{C}P^{2n}]$, and we can check wether $(\alpha^{n}\smile \alpha^{n})\frown [\mathbb{C}P^{2n}]$ is $1$ or $-1$, i.e. we check if $\alpha^{2n}:=\alpha^{n}\smile \alpha^{n}$ is the dual of the fundamental class or not. in the first case, $\sigma(\mathbb{C}P^{2n})=1$, in the other case $\sigma(\mathbb{C}P^{2n})=-1$. So it's just a matter of wether the element $\alpha$ "induces" the chosen orientation or not.

**I'm aware** that this reasoning is somewhat sloppy, BUT I really didn't find anything else, and I can't prove the passage tom Dieck does with the induced map $p_*,p^*$ in (co)-homology.

So I'm here asking if someone has a better proof of this fact OR can explain why (according to tom Dieck), $p^*(\alpha) = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n$, where $\alpha_i$ is the dual of the fundamental class of the $i$-th copy of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ in $(\mathbb{C}P^1)^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain why $p^*(\alpha)=\alpha_1+\dots+\alpha_n$.  We have $H_2((\mathbb{C}P^1)^n)=\mathbb{Z}^n$, with basis $(i_k)_*(x)$, where $i_k:\mathbb{C}P^1\to (\mathbb{C}P^1)^n$ is the inclusion of the $k$th factor and $x\in H_2(\mathbb{C}P^1)$ is the fundamental class.  Explicitly, choosing $[0,1]$ as a basepoint for $\mathbb{C}P^1$, the map $i_k$ is defined by $i_k([a,b])=([0,1],\dots,[0,1],[a,b],[0,1],\dots,[0,1])$, where $[a,b]$ is in the $k$th coordinate.  The classes $\alpha_k\in H^2((\mathbb{C}P^1)^n)$ are then just the dual basis to the classes $(i_k)_*(x)$.  Now the composition $pi_k:\mathbb{C}P^1\to\mathbb{C}P^n$ can be explicitly computed to be given by the formula $pi_k([a,b])=[0,0,\dots,0,a,b]$ for each $k$.  That is, $pi_k$ is just the standard inclusion of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ into $\mathbb{C}P^n$.  In particular, this means that $p_*(i_k)_*(x)$ is the same for every $k$ and is a generator of $H_2(\mathbb{C}P^n)=\mathbb{Z}$.  The class $\alpha\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^n)$ then satisfies $\alpha(p_*(i_k)_*(x))=\pm 1$; let's suppose $\alpha(p_*(i_k)_*(x))=1$ (if not, we could just change which generator of $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^n)$ we're calling $\alpha$).

We now have $\alpha(p_*(i_k)_*(x))=1$ for each $k$, or equivalently, $p^*(\alpha)((i_k)_*(x))=1$ for each $k$.  Since the classes $\alpha_k$ are the dual basis to the classes $(i_k)_*(x)$, this means that $$p^*(\alpha)=\sum_k p^*(\alpha)((i_k)_*(x))\alpha_k=\sum_k\alpha_k.$$

In short, the map $p$ might be hard to understand, but its compositions with the inclusions $i_k$ turn out to be very easy to understand, and this is all you need to compute $p^*(\alpha)$.

Comment: wow, you really solve every doubts I could have with this map. Thanks! As a side-note, do you know where this map $p$ comes from? It kind of reminds me the Veronese embedding, even though it is different (not even an embedding I fear). 
Is it "famous"? or it is something build exactly for this proof?

Comment: The map $p$ is well-known, though I don't know of any particular name for it.  It is the quotient map for the group action of $\Sigma_n$ permuting the coordinates of $(\mathbb{C}P^1)^n$, and thus identifies $\mathbb{C}P^n$ with the symmetric power $Sym^n(\mathbb{C}P^1)$.